# jQuery :not() selector is not selecting the inverse of its positive equivalent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm wondering if I may have missed something, the work around I've come up with is frailer than I like. i.e. I would prefer not have to select on some element that isn't really related to what I'm after, in this case, a child div, or specific unrelated hierarchy.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="True" name="outer" id="outer-yes"/> <label for="outer-yes">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" value="False" name="outer" id="outer-no"/> <label for="outer-no">No</label>
        </div>

        <fieldset disabled>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" value="True" name="inner" id="inner-yes"/> <label for="inner-yes">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" value="False" name="inner" id="inner-no"/> <label for="inner-no">No</label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>


$(function(){
    var tests = [
        { filter: 'input:radio[value=False]', expected: 2 },
        { filter: 'input:radio[value=False]:disabled', expected: 1 }, // because I suspected this would not work as expected, i.e. wouldn't detect the parent fieldset disabled attribute
        { filter: 'fieldset:not([disabled]) input:radio[value=False]', expected: 1 }, // I hoped this would work, but apparently we're looking at the top most fieldset, and not the closest fieldset
        { filter: 'fieldset[disabled] input:radio[value=False]', expected: 1 }, // It kind of surprises me that this passes
        { filter: 'fieldset[disabled]>div>input:radio[value=False]', expected: 1 }, // If I do a strict child selection, I get the results I expect, however, this frailer than I'd like.
        { filter: 'fieldset[disabled] div input:radio[value=False]', expected: 1 }
    ];

    var results = [];
    $.each(tests, function(){
        this.actual = $(this.filter).length;
        results.push(this.filter + ': expected: ' + this.expected + ', actual: ' + this.actual + ', pass: ' + (this.expected === this.actual) + '<br/>');
    });

    $('#results').html(results.join(''));
});
```

Here is an accompanying fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Fd2a/6/

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: is it `fieldset:not(:disabled)`? have you tried this?

Comment: What are you after here? Not sure I see a specific question...

Comment: `input:radio[value=False]:disabled: expected: 1, actual: 0, pass: false` i see 0 disabled inputs, therefore 0 is the expected result.

Comment: The problem is the second fieldset is inside the first one

Comment: All of your tests are performing the way they should, you simply are mis-interpreting them. What exactly are you trying to select, and, what is your starting point for making that selection?

Comment: @KevinB Very true. The only question I see here is "Why are my assumptions wrong?" which the answer is "Because you made them that way"

Comment: try fieldset input:radio[value=False]:not(fieldset[disabled] input)

Comment: Question is, why isn't the :not() *not* selecting the inverse of its positive, without adding more specificity to the query.

Comment: @ArunPJohny you're a genius, that worked! Will accept if you post as answer.

Comment: @Dave you have to read it based on where it is. For example, this selector: `fieldset:not([disabled]) input:radio[value=False]` it selects the fieldset that is not disabled, then looks for an input inside of it that is a radio button and has a value of `False`. There are two radio buttons that match that because the second fieldset (the one that is disabled) is inside the first one (the one that isn't), meaning all 4 inputs are inside of the first fieldset.

Comment: Ahhh, that explains why my assumption is false, thanks for the explanation @KevinB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('fieldset input:radio[value=False]:not(fieldset[disabled] input)')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ynf26/)